# lsplog library not found when linking the project with spdlog

Tags: c++, spdlog

i am trying to add logging to my project using spdlog
but the problem is when compiling the project
in the linking stage i get this error
"[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ${project}
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsplog: No such file or dir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

i tried to search if the library is installed or not but did not find it

Comment: Probably there is a typo: splog